# How to replace x-axis in a Matlab figure?

Tags: matlab, graphics, matlab-figure

What commands do I need to shift the x-axis values in an open Matlab figure without affecting the y-axis values?  (as is shown in the images below)

My best guess so far is:

```
LineH = get(gca, 'Children');
x = get(LineH, 'XData');
y = get(LineH, 'YData');

offset=20;

nx = numel(x);
for i=1:nx
    x_shifted{i} = x{i} + offset;
end

set(LineH,'XData',x_shifted')
```

Which gives me the error:

```
Error using matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Line/set
While setting the 'XData' property of Line:
Value must be a vector of numeric type
```

Thanks!

[image: non_shifted_axis] 
[image: shifted_axis]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to encapsulate the [`'XData'` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.line-properties.html#property_d119e565678) name in a cell to update multiple plot objects at a time. From the [`set`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html) documentation:

> `set(H,NameArray,ValueArray)` specifies multiple property values using the cell arrays `NameArray` and `ValueArray`. To set `n` property values on each of `m` graphics objects, specify `ValueArray` as an `m`-by-`n` cell array, where `m = length(H)` and `n` is equal to the number of property names contained in `NameArray`.

So to fix your error, you just have to change the last line to this:

```
set(LineH, {'XData'}, x_shifted');
```

And if you're interested, here's a solution that uses [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) instead of a loop:

```
hLines = get(gca, 'Children');
xData = get(hLines, 'XData');
offset = 20;

set(hLines, {'XData'}, cellfun(@(c) {c+offset}, xData));
```

Answer (score 3):

Apparently you can't set the `'XData'` property of all lines at the same time with a cell array.

*EDIT It can be done; see [@gnovice's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46941729/2586922).*

What you can do is just move the `set` statement into the loop:

```
LineH = get(gca, 'Children');
x = get(LineH, 'XData');
y = get(LineH, 'YData');

offset=20;

nx = numel(x);
for i=1:nx
    x_shifted{i} = x{i} + offset;
    set(LineH(i),'XData',x_shifted{i}); % set statement with index i
end
```